# Warning Message Using Revtex4 in Preamble

Tags: debugging, revtex

I was wondering what was the cause of the following warning! message with the documentclass below:

Using the following:

```
\documentclass[amssymb,twocolumn]{revtex4}
```

**WARNING MESSAGE BELOW**

```
Class revtex4 Warning: No Society specified, using generic APS style.
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You did not specify a society (journal) and therefor it used the generic APS style :-)

**Option** `aps`: American Physical Society, default journal

```
\documentclass[amssymb,twocolumn,aps]{revtex4}
```

**Options** `pra`, `prb`, `prc`, `prd`, `pre`, `prl`, `prstab`:  APS society, Physical Review Journals.

**Option** `osa`: Optical Society of America, default journal, etc.

---

ADDED: Usage of `times` fonts

Make sure that you load `amsmath` before the font commands. With ReVTeX it can be loaded as a class option

```
\documentclass[amsmath,amssymb,twocolumn,osa]{revtex4}
```

Do not use the `times` package because it was superseded by `mathptmx`. Use the following setup but note that the `\bm{}` will use "poorman's bold" because the times do not have bold math symbols

```
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}%.......... Type 1 outline fonts
\usepackage{textcomp}%............. Additional text symbols
\usepackage{mathptmx}%............. Roman+math - Times
\usepackage[scaled=.92]{helvet}%... Sans serif - Helvetica
\usepackage{courier}%.............. Typewriter - Courier
\usepackage{bm}%................... Bold math symbols
```

An alternative is to use the `txfonts` package that has bold math symbols

```
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}%.......... Type 1 outline fonts
\usepackage{textcomp}%............. Additional text symbols
\usepackage{txfonts}%.............. Roman-Times, Sans-Helvetica, TT-Monospaced
\usepackage{bm}%................... Bold math fonts
```

Comment: Thanks for the quick response, I will see if this will fix the problem because I have over 30 TeX files all with that one Warning on them. I like to see 0 errors, 0 warnings, 0 bad boxes when I run my files. ;) .... There is one slight dilemma though. All is fine with the solution to the problem you posted except for the Optical Society of America (OSA) option. It did not build successfully. It could be from the packages I used:

    \usepackage{times,amsmath}

Could you possibly look into that further for me please when you get the chance. But the others worked excellent. Thank You.

Comment: @night owl:  Look at the added material

Comment: There are a couple new aps and aip journals since this answer was given. [Here is a pdf](http://www.physics.csbsju.edu/370/papers/Journal_Style_Manuals/summary4-1.pdf) containing more command options for the newer journals, but I can't figure out whether that list is fully up-to-date. Specifically, I can't figure out what the code is for the new Physical Review Fluids journal is :/

Comment: It would also be great if this answer could specify which options correspond with which journals as it is not always clear from the option code.